# server hacked - cron continue to run

Tags: syslog, hacking

Someone accessed my `EC2` `Ubuntu` 14.04 and installed some malicious `cron` to do port scanning with user `eric`. I removed user `eric` and the file executed, but in `syslog` I see

```
Sep 19 15:27:01 ip-xxx CRON[9388]: Authentication failure
Sep 14 08:45:01 ip-xxx CRON[9389]: (eric) CMD (/var/tmp/.muh/y >/dev/null 2>&1)
Sep 19 15:28:01 ip-xxx CRON[9389]: Authentication failure
Sep 19 15:29:01 ip-xxx CRON[9391]: Authentication failure
Sep 19 15:30:01 ip-xxx CRON[9392]: Authentication failure
Sep 19 15:31:01 ip-xxx CRON[9526]: Authentication failure
```

Can anyone tell me how to find the `cron` installed (`crontab` is empty)?

Comment: @d-milito I _AM_ SysAdmin (check my profile) you have to disable that `cron` job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to all give me an hand to resolve my issue and put -1.

And the real thx to
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/
-rw------- 1   1002 crontab  222 Sep 10 19:13 eric
-rw------- 1 ubuntu crontab 1148 Aug 25 16:44 ubuntu
```

The hackered account eric put in him crontab

```
* * * * * /var/tmp/.muh/y >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now i could fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try one (or two) of these:

- `chmod 000 /var/rmp/.muh/y` (if you want to analyse later)
- `mv /var/tmp/.muh/y /tmp` (move to alternative location)
- `rm /var/tmp/.muh/y` (remove it completely)

then you gotta find where in `cron` it's scheduled and remove it.

Comment: /var/tmp/ is already empty
PS: why you edit my question and highlight some words? Is usefull for users?

Comment: @D.Milito if it's empty, then look wherever it's scheduled from and remove it from there, so it doesn't show up in your `syslog` anymore.

Comment: i can't find where it is scheduled. this is my problem.